# Selection does not contain a main type in maven-archetype-webapp

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I have just created a maven project in Eclipse using the archetype maven-archetype-webapp. Then I right clicked on `src/main/resources` and created a class with a public static void main method:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

Eventually I right clicked on the file and chose `Debug As -> Java Application`. The result has been a popup saying `Selection does not contain a main type`

Comment: Try to create class in folder src/main/java

Comment: There is no java folder inside src/main. There is only a resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not an Eclipse user, but according to maven conventions classes should be created under `src/main/java`. In case you don't have this folder just create manually, it's simple folder.

More information you can reade [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)